# Angularjs controller firing error function after successful post operation in ASP.Net WEBAPI

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've three tables Product, Order and OrderDetails. I'm using AngularJS and ASP.Net WebAPI. Now the problem is, I can insert data successfully in the OrderDetails table. But in callback its calling the error function in place of the success function in angularjs controller though the post operation performed successfully. Can't figure out the problem after searching for a long time.

in my app.js

```
$scope.addorder = function () {
    $http.post('/api/OrderDetails/', $scope.orders).success(function (data) {
        alert("Added Successfully!!");
        $scope.orders = [];
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "Error occured!"
    });
};
```

in my OrderDetailsController.cs

```
    private static readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orders = new OrderDetailRepository();

    // POST api/<controller>
    public Order Post(List<OrderDetail> orderDetails)
    {
        Order aOrder = new Order();
        aOrder.AllOrders = orderDetails;
        aOrder.odate = DateTime.Now;
        return _orders.Add(aOrder);
    }
```

in my OrderDetailsRepository.cs

```
    private readonly MediaSoftContext _db;

    public OrderDetailRepository()
    {
        _db = new MediaSoftContext();
    }        

    public Order Add(Order order)
    {
        _db.Orders.Add(order);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return order;
    }
```

Comment: inspect the actual request in your browser's dev tools network tab to see what is happening.

Comment: it shows 500 internal server error in status

Comment: ok, so that tells you it has nothing to do with angular. Need to check what is sent is what is expected and troubleshoot your server code

Comment: The internal server error normally means an exception was raised and was not handled.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with angular. I guess I have a problem with the return type. But can't figure out what it is.

Comment: maybe I should convert it to Json?

Comment: First you need to find out what's wrong, it can be any number of things. Use try/catch around your Post and find out what the exception message says. That should hopefully give you a clue. My money is on the database addition being wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, a 500 error means a failure *on the server* and is not related to Angular. You need to figure out where the error is occurring on the server using debugging breakpoints.

Also check the network tab for what the payload is being sent to the server.  It's likely sending some sort of serialized array which is not directly available as an `IEnumerable<OrderDetail>`.